# Will an option to migrate to Web Apps be added to Super User's Close dialog?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons

The title says it all really.

Now that <s>Nothing To Install</s> [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) is live, will it be added to the close dialog?

Comment: It certainly should be!

Comment: This is the bottom option on the close box, I guess it probably wasn't 16hrs ago when you asked this though..

Comment: @DMA57361 - That's right. It wasn't there last night.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has now been added.

Comment: Flagged my first question for migration to Nothing To Install - http://superuser.com/questions/111243/unlimited-and-multi-computer-online-storage-solutions-with-automatic-backup

Comment: Perhaps you can make an answer here where you list all the questions you would want migrated or start a chat room for it, so people can pitch in

Comment: @Ivo - I think they should be migrated as and when people come across them. We don't want to flood Nothing To Install with loads of questions in one go.

Comment: Nice, no more cribbing about You *&*&# there <insert-number> open questions on <insert-web-app> why aren't they closed, yadda yadda yadda