# Will an option to migrate to gaming be added to Super User's close dialog?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration

The same request as [this question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1518/will-an-option-to-migrate-to-web-apps-be-added-to-super-users-close-dialog) but for the gaming site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been implemented with a mechanism for all sites.

[Adapt close dialog UI for upcoming avalanche of StackExchange 2.0 graduates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63961/adapt-close-dialog-ui-for-upcoming-avalanche-of-stackexchange-2-0-graduates)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not until it's out of beta

Comment: It's out of beta now - otherwise I wouldn't have asked the question ;)

Comment: @ChrisF - It still has the Beta logo on it's page so I assumed it still was in beta

Comment: It's got the same rocket image as web apps instead of the day count on my Area 51 profile page - http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/87/chrisf - which I assumes means launched, plus I got my Founders badge for it too.